# Is it possible to make it so when ever I launch Google Chrome it launches with a proxy?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

Is it possible to make it so when ever I launch Google Chrome it launches with a proxy? If so, how?

I'm basically trying to make my browsing as anonymous as possible. However, I don't want to have to go to a web service every time I log on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to:

settings => options => under the Hood => change proxy setting => LAN setting => Proxy server

Now configure your own!

Comment: http://www.google.com/support/chrome/?hl=en

Comment: Any good tutorials on how to configure one?

Comment: Do you know your proxy server name or IP and port? Are you novice to proxy server?

Comment: Nevermind figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome has a command-line switch to set the proxy.

See [this extract from the sources](http://www.ericdlarson.com/misc/chrome_command_line_flags.html).

The switch is: --proxy-server